# PHP form issue after submit

Tags: php, forms, smarty, oxid

ill try to submit this form:

```
<form name="quick_login" class="loginfrm" action="[{$oViewConf->getSelfActionLink()}]cl=subtel_account_extend_bill_details" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="oxid" name="oxid" value="[{$oViewConf->getoxtrckID()}]">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="loginEmail_[{$style}]">[{oxmultilang ident="WIDGET_LOGINBOX_EMAIL_ADDRESS"}]</label>
        <input type="text" id="email_track" name="email_track" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ordernr_track_[{$style}]">[{*oxmultilang ident="WIDGET_LOGINBOX_PASSWORD"*}]Order number</label>
        <input type="text" id="ordernr_track" name="ordernr_track" class="form-control" required >
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn [{if $style eq 'desktop'}]btn-sm[{else}]btn-lg[{/if}] btn-info start_login">[{*oxmultilang ident="LOGIN"*}]Show order</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</form>
```

after fill in email and ordernr. ill get redirectet to an empty page when i debug i gett my oxid. I want to get the oxid first and redirect after getting the oxid so i can go to the order im searching for.

ill try a lot of things these past 2 days but nothing works.

thats my functio to get the oxid

```
public function getoxtrckID()
{
    $sEMail = oxRegistry::getConfig()->getRequestParameter('email_track', true);
    $sONumber = oxRegistry::getConfig()->getRequestParameter('ordernr_track', true);
    $sArticleId = oxDb::getDb()->getOne("SELECT OXID FROM oxorder WHERE OXORDERNR = ? AND OXBILLEMAIL = ?", [$sONumber, $sEMail]);
    return $sArticleId;
}
```

Im not good at JS so ill tryed only php, can someone give me a little help, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need an actual redirect unless you want to prevent visitors from hitting F5 and reloading same page again, which is not necessary here.
Before we start: your variable `$sArticleId` contains an order Id, to keep the code understandable you should name it `$sOrderId`.

After you found your order Id you also need to load the order data like this:

```
$oOrder = oxNew("oxorder");
$oOrder->load($sOrderId);
```

In order to keep it simple, you can remove your hidden order id field, put the code for loading the order data into the `render()` function and pass the order object to the view (template):

```
public function render()
{
  ... your render code ...

  $sEMail = oxRegistry::getConfig()->getRequestParameter('email_track', true);
  $sONumber = oxRegistry::getConfig()->getRequestParameter('ordernr_track', true);
  // if form was submitted, both variables will be set
  if($sEMail && $sONumber)
  {
    // finding order 
    $sOrderId = oxDb::getDb()->getOne("SELECT OXID FROM oxorder WHERE OXORDERNR = ? AND OXBILLEMAIL = ?", [$sONumber, $sEMail]);

    if($sOrderId) // order found -> loading order data
    {
      $oOrder = oxNew("oxorder");
      $oOrder->load($sOrderId) 
      $this->addTplParam('oOrder', $oOrder);
    }
    else // order not found, display error message
    {
      oxRegistry::get("oxUtilsView")->addErrorToDisplay('Order not found'); 
    }
  }
  return $sTempalteName;
}
```

In your template you will get the oxOrder object will all the properties and methonds:

```
[{if $oOrder}]
  <h2>Your Order Data:</h2>
  [{$oOrder->oxorder__whateveryouwant->value }]
[{/if}]
```

Comment: thanks for the help and the good explanation, its finally working